# getting error solidity-member-transfer-not-found-or-not-visible-after-argument-dependent

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I am trying to create one contract for Lottary app however I am getting error as

" browser/test.sol:103:9: TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
        users[luckyNumber].transfer(address(this).balance);"

I tried to make  address[] users as  address payable [] users; mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499997/solidity-member-transfer-not-found-or-not-visible-after-argument-dependent then it give different error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


/*
Lottery is safe under the assumption that miners do not interfere,
no smart contract can hack me (If You can prove me otherwise :D )
*/
contract LotteryFor10{

address[] users; 
mapping(address => bool) participated;
uint256 public constant WAIT_BLOCKS_LIMIT = 3 ;
uint256 public registeredCount ;
uint256 public _registeredLimit ;
uint256 constant REGISTERING_PARTICIPANTS = 1;
uint256 constant REGISTERING_FINISHED = 2;
uint256 constant WAITING_FOR_RANDOMNESS = 3;
uint256 constant SOLVING_LOTERRY = 4;
uint256 constant LOTTERY_SOLVED = 5;
uint256 public waitingStartBlockNumber;
bool public lotterySolved;

constructor(uint256 _limit) public{
    waitingStartBlockNumber = 0;
    registeredCount = 0;//good habit not to rely on defaults if You do 
 not have to
    _registeredLimit = _limit;
}



function () public payable{

    if(getStage(block.number)==REGISTERING_PARTICIPANTS){
        processAddingUser(msg.sender);
    }
    else{ // this else is crutial so we never enter two stages in same 
   call
        if(getStage(block.number)==REGISTERING_FINISHED){
            require(msg.value == 0,"no additional stake allowed");
            waitingStartBlockNumber = block.number;
            emit ClosingList(waitingStartBlockNumber);
        }
        else{
            if(getStage(block.number)==WAITING_FOR_RANDOMNESS){
                    require(msg.value == 0,"no additional stake 
   allowed");

                    revert("To little time passed, wait at least 
  WAIT_BLOCKS_LIMIT ");
            }
            else{
                if(getStage(block.number)==SOLVING_LOTERRY){
                    require(msg.value == 0,"no additional stake 
                    allowed");
                    processSolvingLottery(block.number);
                }
                else{        
                    revert("Lottery Closed ");
                 }
               }
           }
         }
      }


   function getStage(uint256 blockNum) private view returns(uint256) {
    if(registeredCount<_registeredLimit){
        return REGISTERING_PARTICIPANTS;
    }
    else{
        if(waitingStartBlockNumber==0 //start waiting block has been 
                   never set
            || blockNum-waitingStartBlockNumber>=256 //start waiting 
                block has been set long time ago
            ){
            return REGISTERING_FINISHED;
        }
        else
        {
            if(blockNum-waitingStartBlockNumber<WAIT_BLOCKS_LIMIT){
                return WAITING_FOR_RANDOMNESS;
            }
            else{
                if(lotterySolved == true){
                    return LOTTERY_SOLVED;
                }
                else{
                    return SOLVING_LOTERRY;
                 }
               }
            }
         }
      }

   function processAddingUser(address sender) private{
     require(msg.value==1 finney,"Must send 0.001 ether");
    require(participated[sender]==false,"One address can pericipate 
    only once");
    require(registeredCount<_registeredLimit,"ups getStage() do not 
     work");
    participated[sender] = true;
    users.push(sender);
    registeredCount = registeredCount+1;
    emit UserRegistered(sender);
 }

  function processSolvingLottery(uint256 blockNum) private{
    uint256 luckyNumber = 
    uint256(blockhash(waitingStartBlockNumber+WAIT_BLOCKS_LIMIT));
    luckyNumber = luckyNumber % _registeredLimit;
    users[luckyNumber].transfer(address(this).balance);<---- error is 
    here 
    emit UseRewarded(users[luckyNumber],blockNum);
    lotterySolved = true;
 }

event ClosingList(uint256 blockNum);
event UserRegistered(address adr);
event UseRewarded(address adr,uint256 blockNum);
 }
```

Comment: What compiler version are you using? Your code compiles fine under 0.4.24.

Comment: yes however I also tried new version pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

Comment: If you are using higher (above 0.5.0) compiler version, can you try making address (users[luckyNumber]) to payable

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
users[luckyNumber].transfer(address(this).balance);
```

with

```
payable(users[luckyNumber]).transfer(address(this).balance);
```